# RemoteUserMiddleware is not working, it just redirects me to /accounts/login/?next=

Tags: python, django, authentication, remoteusermiddleware

I am trying to just have simple, `WWW-Authenticate` HTTP authentication in Django using `REMOTE_USER`. This is done with [RemoteUserMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/#configur.).

Unfortunately, after changing my config file like such:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
)
```

and adding `@login_required` decorator to my view, it is not working. When I view the page, it directs me to `accounts/login/?next=/page/I/tried/to/access`, which doesn't exist and raises a 404 error.

Why doesn't it just send `WWW-Authenticate`? If this isn't the right way to do that, how can I?

Comment: `RemoteUserMiddleware` isn't used to implement basic authentication, it's used to handle people who logged on using basic authentication by some other source (like Apache configured to use htpasswd). Django doesn't support basic authentication out of the box, but [django-basic](http://code.google.com/p/django-basic/) says it can provide it.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for your answer, I was able to use it after adding a `Location` directive in Apache with `AuthType Basic` and the rest. I misunderstood what the middleware was actually for.